# Display image in imageView from gridView(All images fetch from database)

Tags: android, gridview

I want to set Image in ImageView. This Image from gridView.All images in gridview Are fetch From MySql DataBase at runtime.Here is my code.

GalleryFragment.java

```
public class GalleryFragment extends Fragment {
GridView grid;
private List<User> userList;



@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gallery, null);

    grid=(GridView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.grid);

    imagesFromDb();


    return rootView;
}
private void imagesFromDb() {
    //Code Which Is Get all images from database
    setData();
    }
private void setData() {
        AdapterGallery adapter = new AdapterGallery(getActivity(),userList);
        grid.setAdapter(adapter);
        grid.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), Galleryfullimage.class);
            i.putExtra("id", position);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });

}
}
```

AdapterGallery.java

```
public class AdapterGallery extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    private List<User> userList;

    public AdapterGallery(Context context, List<User> userList){
        mContext=context;
        this.userList=userList;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return userList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        //View grid;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gallerysecond, null);

        TextView en = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.grid_text);
        ImageView imageView= (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.grid_image);

        User contacts = userList.get(position);
        en.setText(contacts.gall_name);
        Picasso.with(mContext).load(ServerHelper.galleryimgpath+contacts.gall_img)
                .placeholder(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher))
                .error(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ramanisir)).into(imageView);

        Log.e("Path", ServerHelper.galleryimgpath + contacts.gall_img);

        return convertView;

    }
}
```

Galleryfullimage.java

```
    public class Galleryfullimage extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.galleryfullimage);
   }

}
```

What i do for display Full Image in Galleryfullimage.java?i have layout file galleryfullimage.xml. In that file one ImageView is there.

Please Guide me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the issue you facing with your code.

Comment: You will have to load the full image separately as picasso will load images according to the size of imageview you are loading it in.

Comment: If i click on image in gridView than it does not display full image.

Comment: You should pass imageName in OnItemClick to GalleryFullImage Activity and use that to show to full image view with picasso code, check readyandroid answer.

Comment: Use `Picasso` or `Glide` for load images.

Answer (score 1):

Change your OnItemClick in GalleryFragment with:

```
 @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                        int position, long id) {
           Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), Galleryfullimage.class);
           i.putExtra("User_Image", userList.get(position).gall_img);
           startActivity(i);          
    }
```

Next usage in  Galleryfullimage  activity:

```
public class Galleryfullimage extends Activity {
     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.galleryfullimage);
         String imageName = getIntent().getStringExtra("User_Image");
         //Now show this image to imageview using same picasso code
         Picasso.with(this).load(ServerHelper.galleryimgpath+imageName )
         .placeholder(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher))
         .error(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ramanisir))
         .into(imageView/*Full image view*/);
       }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are passing only position to the GallaryFullImage Activity. 
So in new activity you will not have object reference of particular Grid Model.
So Instead of passing just position, pass full path of Image as intent parameter like this.

```
 grid.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                  User contacts = ((User) grid.getAdapter()).getItem(position);
                  Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(),Galleryfullimage.class);
                //i.putExtra("id", position);
                  i.putExtra("Path", ServerHelper.galleryimgpath + contacts.gall_img);
                  startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

then get this path in Gallaryfullimage Activity and set it.

Comment: Thanks... for answer